# How to download wikipedia articles and store in a database

Tags: html, xml, database, text, wikipedia

I have this web application that users (mainly English learners or children) can search for some existing licensed articles in my database. They can be filtered by categories, tags and how difficult each one is.

So I am thinking of adding articles from Wikipedia to the database and be able to update the articles in my database once in a while but I am not sure what would be the best way for that. My understanding is that I need to download compressed files every time  and then decompress them so I will get articles in XML format. Then I can add them to the database according to the tags? Is there a way I can have it update automatically? I read the article but on data dumps but not sure how to get started.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#SQL_schema

Comment: You will need a User Account first, just incase you didnt know ;).  Secondly, you will need to gain access to their API Web Service, at which point you will need to handle the XML result they return through the call.

Comment: @GoldBishop You can use Wikipedia's API even without an account, just in case you didn't know. And the dumps Ruby mentioned are not related to the API in any way.

Comment: @svick Without the Account, dont you have to get an Authorization Cookie?  WIth the account you just pass in your unique account id with another authentication string and you can do it all from your desktop.

Comment: @GoldBishop I'm not completely sure what you're talking about, but no, you don't have to do anything special if you don't have an account. And I have no idea how is it related to my desktop or what “another authentication string” is (it certainly doesn't have anything to do with the Wikipedia API).

Comment: @svick just wondering cause i had to post some authentication strings on other mediawiki implementations and just thought that the same was true with wikipedia, my mis-information.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps it would be better to merely crawl and index Wikipedia. Then you can store a search index with the *pages you care about* in a system such as Apache Solr. If you do that, **be sure to be polite about the rate of your requests**,

That avoids the storage and requires no effort to get the content updated. Only the links need to be updated (probably much less frequently).

If you don't wish to filter what people find, then you could probably just sign up for [Google's search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) and save the crawler time/effort...

Comment: Since I don't know much about web technologies, I have a few more questions. But if there are many users searching for articles on the application then is it better to just store everything in the database like what I have done with other articles so it is easier to search and display them.

Comment: You really shouldn't crawl Wikipedia directly. If you want just a few articles, use the API. If you want all of them, use the dumps.

Comment: This depends on whether or not you want a limited set of data or general access to wikipedia. IANAL, but as I understand it you are not allowed to reproduce wikipedia wholesale unless you use a CC-BY-SA license yourself. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Mirrors_and_forks. This more or less means if you want to give people in your application general access to their content, you have to link to it rather than reproducing it.  Due to the time involved in crawling at an acceptable rate (weeks), re-using Google's crawl via their api is probably best.

Comment: I think the license is not a major hurdle, if you say that the content of the article is licensed under CC-BY-SA and link to the original on Wikipedia (for attribution), you should be perfectly fine. And again, crawling the site directly (or indirectly through Google) is most likely not the best solution, there are better ones (the API or the dumps).

Comment: But at what point does your work become a derivitive work? If you don't have more content than the wikipedia content included, aren't you really just a fork? imagine I write one article and a lightweight presentation framework then add 50,000 articles from wikipedia.... Where is the boundary? It seems very unclear to me.

Comment: Share Alike — If you alter, transform, or **build upon** this work, you may distribute the resulting work only under the same, similar or a compatible license.